# Colorize or replace the color of a textured image by a specified color using javascript and HTML5 canvas.Like color blend mode in PS

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-processing

I have a textured image with color. What i want is to change the color of the image but retaining its texture. i already know  how to get the data of an image,pixel by pixel(the rgb values).
here's the sample image:[image]

i want it to be colored into these:[image]

Comment: I suppose, if changing color is your only requirement, then CSS filters can do your job.

Comment: yes i want to change the color but by using javascript or jquery because the color will be specified by the user.im using html5 canvas

Comment: Take a look here : http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html, you can use `-webkit-filter` which is although a very recent thing.

Comment: If you add the picture with css then use this as your jquery..... $('#ID').css('background', #'FFF') or just the color $('#ID').css('color', #'FFF')

Comment: the webkit filter is not compatible to all browsers. a reason why i dont want to use it..but i'll try your suggestion..i want it to be dyanmic..because there would be a lot of images to recolor..that's why i wnat to use javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an interactive solution. Run it from localhost and specify a valid image.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    var srcImg = byId('srcImg');

    byId('hueSlider').style.width = srcImg.width + "px";
    var destImg = byId('dstImg');
    destImg.width = srcImg.width;
    destImg.height = srcImg.height;
}

function colorize()
{
    var curHue = byId('hueSlider').value;
    var curSat = byId('satSlider').value;// / 100.0;
    var curLum = byId('lumSlider').value / 100.0;
    byId('hueVal').innerHTML = curHue;
    byId('satVal').innerHTML = curSat;
    byId('lumVal').innerHTML = curLum;

    var dst = byId('dstImg');
    var dstCtx = dst.getContext('2d');
    var img = byId('srcImg');
    dstCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dstImgData = dstCtx.getImageData(0,0,dst.width,dst.height);
    var i, j, r,g,b,hsl,rgb, index;
    if (byId('colCheckBox').checked)
    {
        console.log('colourizing');
        for (j=0; j<dst.height; j++)
        {
            for (i=0; i<dst.width; i++)
            {
                index = (i + j*dst.width) * 4;              // 4 bytes/pixel, set index to point to r component of x,y in dst image
                r = dstImgData.data[index+0];
                g = dstImgData.data[index+1];
                b = dstImgData.data[index+2];
                hsl = rgb2hsl (r, g, b);

                hsl.h = curHue;
                //if (hsl.h > 359)
                //  hsl.h -= 360;
                hsl.s = curSat;

                hsl.l *= curLum;

                rgb = hsl2rgb(hsl.h, hsl.s, hsl.l);
                dstImgData.data[index+0] = rgb.r;
                dstImgData.data[index+1] = rgb.g;
                dstImgData.data[index+2] = rgb.b;
            }
        }
        dstCtx.putImageData(dstImgData,0,0);
    }
}

// code taken from nichabi.com
function hsl2rgb (h, s, l) {

    var r, g, b, m, c, x

    if (!isFinite(h)) h = 0
    if (!isFinite(s)) s = 0
    if (!isFinite(l)) l = 0

    h /= 60
    if (h < 0) h = 6 - (-h % 6)
    h %= 6

    s = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, s / 100))
    l = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, l / 100))

    c = (1 - Math.abs((2 * l) - 1)) * s
    x = c * (1 - Math.abs((h % 2) - 1))

    if (h < 1) {
        r = c
        g = x
        b = 0
    } else if (h < 2) {
        r = x
        g = c
        b = 0
    } else if (h < 3) {
        r = 0
        g = c
        b = x
    } else if (h < 4) {
        r = 0
        g = x
        b = c
    } else if (h < 5) {
        r = x
        g = 0
        b = c
    } else {
        r = c
        g = 0
        b = x
    }

    m = l - c / 2
    r = Math.round((r + m) * 255)
    g = Math.round((g + m) * 255)
    b = Math.round((b + m) * 255)

    return { r: r, g: g, b: b }
}


// code taken from nichabi.com
function rgb2hsl (r, g, b) 
{
    var max, min, h, s, l, d
    r /= 255
    g /= 255
    b /= 255
    max = Math.max(r, g, b)
    min = Math.min(r, g, b)
    l = (max + min) / 2
    if (max == min) {
        h = s = 0
    } else {
        d = max - min
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min)
        switch (max) {
            case r:
                h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0)
                break
            case g:
                h = (b - r) / d + 2
                break
            case b:
                h = (r - g) / d + 4
                break
        }
        h /= 6
    }
    h = Math.floor(h * 360)
    s = Math.floor(s * 100)
    l = Math.floor(l * 100)
    return { h: h, s: s, l: l }
}


</script>
<style>
body
{
    background: #888;
}
#hueVal, #satVal, #lumVal
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img id='srcImg' src='handlebars.png'/><canvas id='dstImg'></canvas>
<br>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='colCheckBox' onchange='colorize()' />Colourize</label>
<br>
Hue<input id='hueSlider' onchange='colorize()' type='range' min='0' max='359'/><div id='hueVal'></div><br>
Saturation<input id='satSlider' onchange='colorize()' type='range' value='50' min='0' max='100'/><div id='satVal'></div><br>
Luminance<input id='lumSlider' onchange='colorize()' type='range' min='0' max='200'/><div id='lumVal'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i already thought doing that, but the requirement for me is to, just input the color(in hex value), then the image will be colored according to the specified color.thanks , this would help me a lot.

Comment: That's alright. Since you can map an RGB colour to a HSL one, I guess it may still have utility for you. I suppose you'd just need to change the H channel of the source image to match the H channel of the #rrggbb colour entered. Not sure, too tired. Cheers. :)