# Displaying a specific image on a webpage using the output of paired select boxes

Tags: javascript, html, image

There are lots of tutorials for making paired select boxes, which I've followed but I feel like I've hit the wall of my knowledge and available tutorials when it comes to populating an image div with the value selected in the second select box.

I'm trying to select an astronomical object, and then a colour filter (Red/Green/Blue) to "image it." By which I mean the wavelength of light the fictional telescope would photograph it in for a simulation programme for young telescope users. 
I have photos of each object in each wavelength, I just need to be able to display Nebula M43 in the red wavelength. The script below is abridged but contains 3 options and the JavaScript I've put together to get it as far as populating the the second select box.

Can anyone help me with where I go from here? Even if its telling me the terminology I need to know to search for it myself would help.

Apologies for the poorly worded question - this is my first post on here and I'm still learning.

```js
// object literal holding data for option elements
var Select_List_Data = {
  choices: {
    // name of associated select box

    // names match option values in controlling select box

    0: {
      text: ["Select Filter..."],
      value: ["Berkeley73Red (Rp)", "Berkeley73Green (V)", "Berkeley73Blue (B)"]
    },
    Berkeley73: {
      text: ["Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"],
      value: ["Berkeley73Red (Rp)", "Berkeley73Green (V)", "Berkeley73Blue (B)"]
    },
    Czernik27: {
      text: ["Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"],
      value: ["Czernik27Red (Rp)", "Czernik27Green (V)", "Czernik27Blue (B)"]
    },
    IC349: {
      text: ["Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"],
      value: ["IC349Red (Rp)", "IC349Green (V)", "IC349Blue (B)"]
    }
  }
};

// removes all option elements in select box
// removeGrp (optional) boolean to remove optgroups
function removeAllOptions(sel, removeGrp) {
  var len, groups, par;
  if (removeGrp) {
    groups = sel.getElementsByTagName("optgroup");
    len = groups.length;
    for (var i = len; i; i--) {
      sel.removeChild(groups[i - 1]);
    }
  }

  len = sel.options.length;
  for (var i = len; i; i--) {
    par = sel.options[i - 1].parentNode;
    par.removeChild(sel.options[i - 1]);
  }
}

function appendDataToSelect(sel, obj) {
  var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var labels = [],
    group, opts;

  function addOptions(obj) {
    var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var o;

    for (var i = 0, len = obj.text.length; i < len; i++) {
      o = document.createElement("option");
      o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.text[i]));

      if (obj.value) {
        o.value = obj.value[i];
      }

      f.appendChild(o);
    }
    return f;
  }

  if (obj.text) {
    opts = addOptions(obj);
    f.appendChild(opts);
  } else {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        labels.push(prop);
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
      group = document.createElement("optgroup");
      group.label = labels[i];
      f.appendChild(group);
      opts = addOptions(obj[labels[i]]);
      group.appendChild(opts);
    }
  }
  sel.appendChild(f);
}

// anonymous function assigned to onchange event of controlling select box
document.forms["demoForm"].elements["category"].onchange = function(e) {
  // name of associated select box
  var relName = "choices";

  // reference to associated select box
  var relList = this.form.elements[relName];

  // get data from object literal based on selection in controlling select box (this.value)
  var obj = Select_List_Data[relName][this.value];

  // remove current option elements
  removeAllOptions(relList, true);

  // call function to add optgroup/option elements
  // pass reference to associated select box and data for new options
  appendDataToSelect(relList, obj);
};

// populate associated select box as page loads
(function() {
  // immediate function to avoid globals

  var form = document.forms["demoForm"];

  // reference to controlling select box
  var sel = form.elements["category"];
  sel.selectedIndex = 0;

  // name of associated select box
  var relName = "choices";
  // reference to associated select box
  var rel = form.elements[relName];

  // get data for associated select box passing its name
  // and value of selected in controlling select box
  var data = Select_List_Data[relName][sel.value];

  // add options to associated select box
  appendDataToSelect(rel, data);
})();
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">

  <label class="wrapper" for="states">Target Name</label>
  <div class="button dropdown">
    <select name="category">

      <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a target...</option>
      <option value="Berkeley73">Berkeley 73 (Cluster of Stars -40 sec. avg.)</option>
      <option value="Czernic27">Czernic27 (Open (galactic) Cluster -40 sec. avg.)</option>
      <option value="IC349">IC349 (Reflection Nebula -120 sec. avg.)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div><label class="wrapper" for="states">Filter</label></div>
  <select name="choices" id="choices">
    <!-- populated using JavaScript -->
  </select>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751828/colorize-or-replace-the-color-of-a-textured-image-by-a-specified-color-using-jav/24771339#24771339

Essentially, you draw the picture to a canvas and change it during that step. This means it must run from a server (localhost is okay) othrwise you get a security error when trying to get the values of the image's pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so really what you need to do is call a function `onchange` when your user makes a choice from the options. Bear in mind that the options that you have paired may be changed by the user, so onchange, retrieve the image, then retrieve the desired colour, and then apply the filter. From "filter", it sounds like you want to put the colour over the image? In this case you could create a div and display it in `absolute position` (same position as the image div) and adjust the [`z index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) so that it displays over the image. I wrote some very quick pseudocode (no code - sorry :( ) in a function at the end of your javascript (which seems very long-winded? I didn't study it thoroughly - time issues) . 
I created a div and put a placeholder image in it (you would populate your image into this div and put the filter over it)

EDIT: I updated the snippet with new code (erm.. it's quite different from yours) I have a placeholder image, but there is a commented out line that you can use to populate the image. It helps to set your baseurl in a variable like so:

```
    var baseurl = "https://www.yourdomain.com/images/";
    var $showimg = baseurl + $chosen + ".jpg"; /*or png etc*/

    $(".astro").attr("src",$showimg);
```

I commented the last line out just so that you could see the effect in the snippet.

Hope this helps (someone!)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function getimage() {
    $("#choice").change(function() {
      var $chosen = $("#choice option:selected").val();
      //alert($chosen);
      if ($chosen == "base") {
        alert("Please select an image")
      } else {
        /*set your image source*/
        var baseurl = "https://www.yourdomain.com/images/";
        var $showimg = baseurl + $chosen + ".jpg"; /*or png etc*/
        //alert ("img is " +$showimg);
        //$(".astro").attr("src",$showimg); use this, the next line is demo purposes
        $(".astro").attr("src", "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/Gateway/Brightbuy/bb_green_1._CB457277258_SY260_.jpg");
      }
    });
  });

  $(function applyfilter() {
    $("#filter").change(function() {
      var $filter = $("#filter option:selected").val();
      $("#filtercol").get(0).style.setProperty("background-color", $filter);
      //alert("colour is " + $filter);
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

h4 {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#category,
#filtercol {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  top: 40vh;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
}

.astro {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

#filtercol {
  opacity: 0.1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>
  Target
</h4>
<select id="choice">
  <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Berkeley73">Berkeley 73 (Cluster of Stars -40 sec. avg.)</option>
  <option value="Czernic27">Czernic27 (Open (galactic) Cluster -40 sec. avg.)</option>
  <option value="IC349">IC349 (Reflection Nebula -120 sec. avg.)</option>
</select>

<h4>Filter</h4>

<select id="filter">
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Green</option>
   <option>Blue</option>
</select>


<div id="category">
  <img class="astro" alt="astro chosen" src=" " />

</div>
<div id="filtercol">

</div>
```

Comment: this (rather old!) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/9b3vwa0o/) from my library illustrates 2 images displayed on top of each other in absolute position. Opacity is different in the one that is displayed on the top so that it doesn't completely wipe out the underlying image (it's set to 0.1, but you could set it to 0. Hth.

Comment: I fear I used technical jargon that has been misunderstood, in astronomical terms using a filter means taking an image in a single wavelength of light. So I want to select the object I want to observe and then subsequently the wavelength of light in which to observe it. I have all the images, I just need to be able to pick the correct one now

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help though, I don't want to sound ungrateful!

Comment: @BJG https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0ngmdqak/ fiddle of updated code. You don't need so much javascript.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to do this, but I fear my poorly worded question has led you to believe I was asking for something different. 

A better analogy would be, I have a drop down list with car manufacturers, ford, volvo, VW etc, and when I click an entry on that list, the next select box populates with a list of the cars that manufacturers makes. I would like to be able to show an image of the model of car that gets chosen, eg, specifically a VW Golf, or a Ford Fiesta.

Comment: @BJG I'm only showing one placeholder image because I don't have a range of images at my disposal. If you apply the javascript to your own images, the image will change (you can lose the 'filter'/second image on top, and that part was very badly worded, and misleading). You can populate the select dynamically depending on what is selected various ways. If you have data stored in a database, it's pretty simple. Look at this link https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

Comment: Consider it done (the thank you tick, and the decision to ask a clearer question!)